# create nested json api using mysql in node js and express

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, api, express

**First of all a lot of thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/ for coding contribution in my life and this is my first quastion on https://stackoverflow.com/**

**Here is my problem**

This is my json.js file for front end which is working fine:

```
const Subjects=[
    {id:1,  selectGrade: "LKG", GradeName: "LKG",
        Detail: [
        { Subject: "English", Content: "Private"},
        { Subject: "Math", Content: "Private"}
    ]},
    {id:2,  selectGrade: "UKG", GradeName: "UKG",
        Detail: [
        { Subject: "English", Content: "Private"},
        { Subject: "Math", Content: "Private"},
        { Subject: "Punjabi", Content: "Private"}
    ]},
    {id:3,  selectGrade: "class-1", GradeName: "1st",
        Detail: [
        { Subject: "English", Content: "PSEB"},
        { Subject: "Math", Content: "PSEB"},
        { Subject: "Punjabi", Content: "Private"},
        { Subject: "Hindi", Content: "Private"},
        { Subject: "EVS", Content: "Private"},
        { Subject: "Computer Science", Content: "Private"},
        { Subject: "General Knowledge", Content: "Private"},
        { Subject: "Drawing", Content: "Private"}
    ]}
];
export default Subjects;
```

This is my code for call api in backend {In **subject_details** table **subject_id** is foreign key}

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = express.Router();
Router.get("/", (req, res)=>{
        db.query("SELECT GradeName, Subject, Content FROM subjects INNER JOIN subject_details ON subjects.subject_id = subject_details.subject_id", (err, rows, fields) =>{
        if(!err)
            {res.send(rows);}
        else
            {console.log(err);}
    })
})
module.exports = Router;
```

and it will give me flat result like this:

```
[{"GradeName":"LKG","Subject":"English","Content":"Private"},{"GradeName":"LKG","Subject":"Math","Content":"Private"},{"GradeName":"UKG","Subject":"English","Content":"Private"},{"GradeName":"UKG","Subject":"Math","Content":"Private"},{"GradeName":"UKG","Subject":"Punjabi","Content":"Private"}]
```

**I want result as my json file. I tried too much but nothing useful discover on internet.**

**Please help me**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Try with `res.send(JSON.stringify(row))`

Comment: Thanks sir for reply but using this query : `db.query("SELECT subjects.subject_id, selectGrade, GradeName, GROUP_CONCAT(Subject , Content) FROM subjects LEFT JOIN subject_details ON subjects.subject_id = subject_details.subject_id GROUP BY selectGrade", (err, rows, fields) =>{`
**I got this result**
[{"subject_id":1,"selectGrade":"LKG","GradeName":"LKG","GROUP_CONCAT(Subject , Content)":"MathPrivate,EnglishPrivate"},{"subject_id":2,"selectGrade":"UKG","GradeName":"UKG","GROUP_CONCAT(Subject , Content)":"MathPrivate,EnglishPrivate,PunjabiPrivate"}]
 **NOT AS I WANT**